# How do I add a Filtered Question to search for questions containing content other than just tags?

Tags: feature-request, tag-filters, filtering, tag-sets

As a user of the main Stack Exchange site, I would like to create filters that work just as if I was searching for things on a particular site, but for it to apply to all sites.  Below is my failed attempt.

1. Go to https://stackexchange.com/sites#name
2. Click on Filtered Questions: https://stackexchange.com/filters
3. Click on the New Filter button: https://stackexchange.com/filters/new
4. Type in "[firefox] native" into the "Just questions tagged with" field: [image: My failed attempt]
5. Change the name of the filter, and click the Save Changes button.
6. When the page loads, click on the Edit button.
7. Notice that the text of "[firefox] native" got wiped out and replaced with just "firefox": [image: text content words removed]

If this is user error and this is possible, could someone explain what I'm doing incorrectly?

If this is just not implemented yet, this is a feature request. I believe this is the case, so I am tagging this as *feature-request*.

Comment: Filters are based only on tags and sites (and having no answers, if you pick that option), other criteria are currently not supported.