# How to set a filter on https://stackexchange.com/filters for site recommendation questions about software applications

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, tag-filters, filtering, tag-sets

This is not a duplicate of [How do I add a Filtered Question to search for questions containing content other than just tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260435/289691). The linked question is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). I will focus this question on workarounds.

---

In Nov 2010, a feature rolled out was called **tag sets**<sup>1</sup> AKA *GlobalTag MegaBlender™*. As of October 25, 2023, the feature is still on the Stack Exchange homepage as **Filtered Questions**. The link URL is https://stackexchange.com/filters.

I know that I can create a filter specific to Meta Stack Exchange and a specific to [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation). Is there a way to make the filter return only questions asking for a site recommendation to ask questions about using [application software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software)?

According to Wikipedia,

> An **application program** (**software application**, or **application**, or **app** for short) is a computer program designed to carry out a specific task other than one relating to the operation of the computer itself,[1] typically to be used by end-users.[2] Word processors, media players, and accounting software are examples. The collective noun "**application software**" refers to all applications collectively.[3] The other principal classifications of software are system software, relating to the operation of the computer, and utility software ("utilities").
>
> Applications may be bundled with the computer and its system software or published separately and may be coded as proprietary, open-source, or projects.[4] The term "app" usually refers to applications for mobile devices such as phones.

There are several ways to classify / group apps. I'm looking to create a filter for questions about any application software, excluding system software and utility software. It might be a question looking where to ask for recommendations, development, troubleshooting, license and terms of service, etc.

#### Famous application software by platform

| Cross-Platform | macOS | App Store Google Play | Web | Windows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Facebook Google (Google Search) WhatsApp X (formerly Twitter) | Garage Band | Google Lens | Google Apps Script | Microsoft Access |

###### Thoughts

I thought that it might be possible to use site-specific tags like [ask-different](/questions/tagged/ask-different),[superuser](/questions/tagged/superuser), but

1. Most OP asking for a site recommendation aren't familiar with Meta Stack Exchange tags. The [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) is frequently added by an editor / curator.
2. Not all sites that allow questions about software apps have a tag
3. Tags should not be added *to answer the question*. Ref. [When should site-specific tags be included in site recommendation questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394086/289691)

If possible, the filter might need to be set based on the question or answer content, but that looks impossible. Am I right?

###### Workarounds?

As I mentioned on top of this question, and the answer was posted a bit earlier than this update, there is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) that confirms that I was right. Considering that it's impossible to use tag sets / tag filer /  filtered questions, what workarounds could be used?

###### Related

- [Filter on my accounts in StackExchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78796/289691)
- [What *is* a GlobalTag MegaBlender™?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325859/289691)

###### References

- [1] : [Tag Sets on Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/04/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 1):

I just found a related [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

[How do I add a Filtered Question to search for questions containing content other than just tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260435/289691)

Besides the mandatory tag, it only had [filtering](/questions/tagged/filtering).

---

I will update the below text later.

Assuming that I was right regarding that, it's not possible to create a filter for questions based on the question and answer content and considering that there isn't a specific tag for what I'm looking for, in this case, for asking for a site recommendation to ask questions about application software, the **workaround** is to set a broad filter, i.e., all questions from Meta Stack Exchange, then use client-side (email client, RSS client) filtering features.

Other workarounds imply using other tools like the Data Explorer, Stack Exchange API and saving a search as a bookmark. An "advanced" workaround could be to use third-party services like [Programmable Search Engine](https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/about/), formerly known as Custom Search Engine.

---

Sample searches

- [[site-recommendation] app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsite-recommendation%5D+app)
  Need to refine this search to exclude

  - "job offer" like [Is there a site for app development job offers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313557/289691). It's closed and has two close-to-delete votes.
  - "app store approval " like [Would questions about App Store approval be appropriate for SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131388/289691). It's about commercial / partnership policies.
  - "pay tax" like [Where can I ask this question - Paying Tax In Multiple Countries? | Apple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300120/289691). Similar to the above.